# vb.net get the last ID and display it

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, scope-identity

i need to get the last ID from a table and display it. I've tried Scope_Identity() but somehow i could not manage to get it. the message box shows nothing.. it's empty. here is my current code:

```
Try
  myConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=192.168.2.222;Initial Catalog=test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sa;"
  myConn.Open()

  myCmd = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY AS LastId FROM customers", myConn)
  oResult = myCmd.ExecuteScalar()

  If oResult IsNot Nothing Then
    MsgBox(oResult.ToString)
  Else
    MsgBox("No Record Found")
  End If

Catch ex As Exception
  MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
  myConn.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: Seems SCOPE_IDENTITY (only?) works after an insert SQL Statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your I'd column is numeric you can use max :

```
 SELECT MAX(ID) AS LastId FROM customers
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ==>

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID AS LastId FROM customers ORDER BY ID DESC
```

This assumes that your 'customers' table has an ID column which is your PK.